# Update a average from two tables?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I want to update a collunm in table A(CSEReduxResponses). The collumn will be 'AVERAGE', it will belong to table  CSEReduxResponses.
I have a query that gets the total starts

```
<cfquery datasource="Intranet" name="GroupStars">
    SELECT execoffice_status, employeedept, COUNT(*) as 'totalstars'
    FROM CSEReduxResponses
    WHERE execoffice_status = 1
    GROUP BY execoffice_status, employeedept
</cfquery>
```

In this other query i have the total count

```
 <cfif GetTotalStars.RecordCount gt 0>
        <cfquery datasource="PhoneList" name="GetAllData">
            SELECT dept.csedept_id, COUNT(*) as 'totalcount'
            FROM employee, dept
            WHERE employee.dept_id = dept.dept_id
                AND employee.emp_status = 1
                AND dept.csedept_id is not null
            GROUP BY dept.csedept_id
        </cfquery>
```

to get the 'AVERAGE' i will divide totalstars / totalcount , and that answer
goes into the 'AVERAGE' Collumn,
How would i join this two tables and get the average?

Comment: One of the principles of normalized databases is to not store calculated values.  Looking at your question, it looks like you might be able to relate CSEReduxResponses to dept, but it also looks like you will updating more rows than you should.  I suggest taking another look at your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfset avg = GroupStars.totalstars / GetAllData.totalcount>
<cfquery name="qUpdateAvg" datasource="Intranet">
    UPDATE CSEReduxResponses
    SET AVERAGE = <cfqueryparam value="#avg#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
    WHERE execoffice_status = 1
</cfquery>
```

Change the cfsqltype to your actual column type.

Comment: I keep getting this error "[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.1' to data type int. " , any suggestion on how to fix?

Comment: Nothing in this answer deals with departments.  Reading the question, that's probably part of the equation.